Entity Framework Core & PostgreSQL '...get_Settings()' failed
I got an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API written in C# and want scaffold a PostgreSQL database with Entity Framework Core 6.
While executing the following command I'm getting an error with not much information on what could be wrong...
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Host=pi;Database=mydb;Username=root;Password=mypw" 
       Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL --project=myAPI --verbose

The following error occur:

Attempt by method 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Scaffolding.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseModelFactory.PopulateGlobalDatabaseInfo(Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Metadata.DatabaseModel)' to access method 'Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.get_Settings()' failed.

The server runs on a raspberry pi inside a docker container, this infrastructure does work completely, as I can connection with a shell from my device to the database. I use the latest docker image version of postgresql.
Here are the versions of the Nuget packages I installed:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (6.0.22)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design (6.0.22)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (6.0.22)
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL (6.0.22)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (6.5.0)

I also tried to create the dbContext by myself, but the same error occurs if i want to access any data from the database. The connection could be established, because if I change the password in the connection string, an authentication exception occurs.

There was a postgresql process running in the background on my device. I ended the process and everything works fine now. Somehow they had a conflict i think...
